# Is there any way no to return a document if the word present in one list

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have document below

```
[
{'id':1, 'name': 'sachin messi', 'description': 'football@football.com', 'type': 'football', 'var':'sports'},
{'id':2, 'name': 'lionel messi', 'description': 'messi@fifa.com','type': 'soccer','var':'sports'},
{'id':3, 'name': 'sachin tendulkar', 'description': 'was', 'type': 'cricket', 'var':'sports'}
]
```

I have one list var.txt contain

```
sachin
```

- I have to avoid sachin from the document

DSL query is below

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "var.keyword": [
                            "sports"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "sach* OR mess*",
                        "fields": [
                            "name^1024",
                            "description^32"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My Output  is below

```
{'took': 128,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': {'value': 2, 'relation': 'eq'},
  'max_score': 1201.876,
  'hits': [{'_index': 'newtestplayer',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': '3',
    '_score': 1201.876,
    '_source': {'id': 3,
     'name': 'sachin tendulkar',
     'description': 'was',
     'type': 'cricket',
     'var': 'sports'}},
   {'_index': 'newtestplayer',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': '2',
    '_score': 929.40845,
    '_source': {'id': 2,
     'name': 'lionel messi',
     'description': 'messi@fifa.com',
     'type': 'soccer',
     'var': 'sports'}}]}}
```

- You can see my query `"sach* OR mess*"`
- My Expected should contain only `id:1 and id:2` and not contain id:3

This is working if my setting is added as `sachin` as stopwords and I need to search like `"sachin OR mess*"`

My requirement is `my output document should not appear if word contain sachin even if i m searching *sach*`

- so this cannot done from stop words if my document is contain 'sachi' and i m searching for sach* then 'sachin' should not come and sachi document should come

Comment: can you elaborate your use case more? also do you have a dynamic list of words which you want to exclude from your search results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `must_not` [query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) inside `bool` from Elasticsearch.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "var.keyword": [
              "sports"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "sach* OR mess*",
            "fields": [
              "name^1024",
              "description^32"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "sachin",
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "description"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any way since i have lots of words just like sachin

Comment: between must_not is working

Comment: @sim You want to remove this list of word for only one query or all the query ?

Comment: all the query i need to remove

Comment: @sim then you can define this word as stop wrods and remove while indexing itself. So this words will be not avilable for search. But you will be able to see in original content.

Comment: no sagar, if `sachin' is in stopwords if i m searching query_string  sach* then also sachin document will appear

Comment: @sim Right, that is happening because you have `OR` condition in `query_string`. but you will get only `id:1` result and not `id:3` result. To resolve this issue you can use `terms` query inside `must_not`.

Comment: My list of words is very huge, is there any way to achieve this without must_not

Comment: @sim as of now i cant see another option. You may try out search template where you will create static query with all the list of word you want to exclude and then you can call search template for executing query.

Comment: Ok, one more thing using `must_not` id:1 has to come if i m searching "sach* OR mess*" because messi is part of the name

Comment: @sim no it will not come because it will remove document where `sachin` term is available. If you want this kind of result then i am pretty sure it will work with stopword as i mentioned in previous comment. So if you add sachin in stop word then only `id:1` result come as you are trying `OR` condition in query but `id:3` will not come.

Comment: correct, for stopwords if i m searching in query string sac* but sachin is coming

Comment: but it will return you only id:1 doc and not id:3 because id:1 have messi as well in name.